# C function declaration

Tags: c, function

can we declare a function in a header file in following way?

```
extern int ap( char[][] );
```

can we use char[][] in function?

Comment: why don't you try it and find out.

Comment: @darren: "Trying it" is very rarely the right way to test the validity of a language contruct. There are quite enough victims of "it works in GCC" out there (for one example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a two dimensional array, you have to supply a size for the last dimension otherwise the compiler doesn't know how to use it.  (it's fine to omit the name though.)

like this:

```
extern int ap( char[][10] );
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you need to specify the last N-1 dimensions for an array.

```
extern int ap( char[][DIMENSION] );
```

For more information look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)

Answer (score 4):

`char[][]` is not a valid array type because you cannot have arrays of an incomplete type, and `char[]` is incomplete.  I know that's confusing because you really have two array types, so here's another example with the same problem: `char a[3][]`.  The array *a* has length 3 and element type of `char[]`, but `char[]` is, again, incomplete and this is [invalid](http://codepad.org/HMCw7AF7).

When you have a "multidimentional array", you really have an array of arrays.  For example, `typedef int U[3][5];` makes *U* an array of length 3 of arrays of length 5 of ints and is equivalent to `typedef int H[5]; typedef H U[3];`.

The reason you may omit the leftmost dimension with function parameters is because, *with function parameters only*, array types of the form `T[N]` are transformed into `T*`, and *N* can be left out, giving `T[]` to `T*`.  This only applies at the "topmost" or "outermost" level.

So, all these function declarations are identical:

```
int f1(int a[3][5]);
int f2(int a[][5]);
int f3(int (*a)[5]);
typedef int T[5];
int f4(T a[3]);
int f5(T a[]);
int f6(T* a);
```

You can, of course, delete the parameter name *a* in any of the above declarations without changing them.

Answer (score 1):

Yet, it is perfectly valid to omit parameter names in function declarations. When you **define** the function, however, you must give the array a name, and then you can refer to it by this name.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed - it attempts to declare the parameter as a pointer to an incomplete array type.

The array type must be completed with a size, like this:

```
extern int ap( char[][10] );
```